# Buscar registro mas utilizado mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

estoy trabado con una consulta y no se me ocurre como realizarla.
Tengo una tabla en una db mysql que almacena todos los pedidos realizados por una remiseria, guarda un numero de pedido, un numero de movil y una descripción.

Necesito consultar que numero de movil es el que realizo mas pedidos y cuantos pedidos realizo este.

Mi tabla:

```
pedido || movil || descripcion
   1         40       auto
   2         20       auto
   3         40       auto
```

En el caso de este ejemplo la consulta me debería de devolver
movil 40 pedidos 2.

Comment: Para evitar te cierren la pregunta, lee [ask], edita y muestra que llevas

Comment: group by.. having.. probaste algo?

Answer (score 0):

Despues de leer tu aclaracion te propongo la siguiente consulta

```
Select count(movil), movil
From tabla
Group by movil
Having count(movil) = (select max(total) from (select count(movil) as total from tabla 
Group by movil) limit 1)
```

Lo que se hace aki es que selecciono el movil y el total de veces que sale este movil , en la clausula having pongo un select que me va a devolver el movil que mas veces esta repetido y este valor es el que uso para comparar y saber precisamente el movil que mas sparece en la tabla

Segun tu ejemplo el redultado de esta consulta seria

2|40 donde 2 es la cantidad de repeticioned y 40 es el movil

Comment: Revisa lo nuevo que puse

Comment: Hola podrias decirme si esta solucion te fue util